# How does Picasso's disk caching work?

Tags: android, caching, picasso

I am using Picasso for loading images.I have enabled debug flags which show if the image is being loaded from RAM,disk or network.

From the flags i got to know that it is using the RAM by default for caching. If I use the skipMemoryCache() method it is automatically using disk caching instead of the RAM.

So, my questions are:
    1.How long do the cached images exist in the disk(and RAM)?
    2.How to manually clear this cache(both disk and RAM) if needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1.How long do the cached images exist in the disk(and RAM)?
```

the cached is a `LRU` (least recently used). By default Picasso try to allocate around 15% of the heap available for your app as runtime cache and around 2% for the disk cache. When the RAM cache is full, and you try to add a new item to it, the *least* is removed from the cache to make space for the newest

```
2.How to manually clear this cache(both disk and RAM) if needed?
```

you cause one of the `invalidate()` methods provided by the library